# Action Script 3. How to add stroke on button's label via AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button, actionscript, stroke

I need to add stroke on button's label useing Action Script 3.

For now I use this:

```
var stroke:GlowFilter = new GlowFilter(0x86564e, 1, 2, 2, 10, 1);
myButton.filters = [stroke];
```

But this add stroke (glow) on the button, not on the button's label. Also I've tried `myButton.label.filters = [stroke];` but unsuccessfully.

It return me following error:

```
1119: Access of possibly undefined property filters through a reference with static type String.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think error reason is that `myButton.label` is not DisplayObject

Comment: Thank you for answer, so how can I make It DisplayObject?

Comment: you can write me types of myButton and label?

Comment: It's MovieClip button created via Flash. And myButton is Instance name of button.

Comment: and label type? what kind of label do you want? you can use textfield as label which be child of you mybutton object